# Speech Recognizer return listens to just the beginning of the audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am using Python's `SpeechRecognition` to extract text from an audio file. The issue I'm having is that it only works on the very few seconds of the clip. This is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as spr

AUDIO_FILE = "file.wav"

recognizer = spr.Recognizer()

with spr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source: 
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2) 
    audio = recognizer.record(source)
    text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='es-CL')
print(text)
```

The recognition works alright, but just for the very few seconds. Namely, `text` contains the words corresponding to the first 7 seconds of an audio clip that is 59 seconds long.

I don't see how this could be happening, maybe because there is a silence in the clip and the recognizer assumes that the audio has ended? Is there any way to configure this parameter (if it exists)? If it's not the case, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could google it, I found out that you need to either give a duration for the system to listen to the whole file or iterate the `recog1.listen(source)` part until the end of the file, because [in this link](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c89856088ad81d81d38be314e3db50905481c5fe/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L215) you are able to inspect the source code and it says on line 215 something like "If you specify 10 seconds duration, then in every iteration you will get the next 10 seconds of the file". I hope it works out.